Understanding 4000 series datasheet for output current values
Edit: the main point of my question is to manage understanding data sheet information as they are written.
Beginner question, I am playing with 555, 4000 series IC and BJT for fun, but electronic is not my background.
I try to understand how much current and which output voltage a 4000 IC like a CD4024BC (binary counter) can provide. But I have hard time understanding the data sheet.
I managed to find some articles saying that if short-circuited, a 4000 output will have its current limited (like for instance 10 mA for a 9 V supply). And also that we can safely add a LED without any resistor (indeed, my LED seems to be driven with a 6.8 mA current at 5 V; if I add a 270 ohm resistor, it seems to be cut in half).
Articles are:

https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/led-chaser-sequencer-circuits
https://electronicsclub.info/cmos.htm (general chararasteristics, output)

But I am lost reading the datasheet of the 4024 (and other 4000 IC) to understand this behavior.
Some datasheets I used:

https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4024BC.pdf
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4024b.pdf?ts=1731172751066

What seems related is the mention of "high level output current", but for VDD = 5V, I have values like -0.51 mA minimum and -0.88 mA typical:

no maximum?
why negative?
why minimum, is it the value in case of shortcircuit, but it does not feel right since I observed higher absolute values

The important thing seems to be that each output must not deliver more than 100 mW of power, and that the chip must not deliver more than 500 mW in total.
However with the above information, I do not understand how I can:

anticipate the output current is limited when shortcircuited
anticipate if I have to put a resistor for a LED (or between another IC), and with which value

Do you have some advices, clues, complementary information? Thank you!

The two conditions for sinking and sourcing current to/from one of the IC's  outputs would resemble this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Both currents are labelled positive, because the arrow points in the direction that conventional current would flow in those circumstances. However, for algebraic consistency we don't usually change arrow directions to imply a change of current direction. Rather we keep the arrow pointing the same way in all schematics, and use the sign of the current to indicate actual direction, with the understanding that a negative sign indicates conventional current flowing in the direction opposing the arrow:

simulate this circuit
The authors of your linked 4020 datasheet have chosen that a positive current should represent current being sunk into an output, and negative is being sourced, as shown immediately above. That's why current sourced from an output is shown as negative in the table on page 3:

Unless you are operating the device at extreme temperatures, you are interested in the red boxed section. Looking also at the \$V_O\$ parameter, that value tells you what voltage was measured at the output pin, for the various sourced/sunk currents shown in the red box.
For the output to source current, it needs to be "high", higher in potential than the far side of the load, which is shown to be ground (0V) above right. Conversely, for an output to sink current, it must be lower in potential than the source of that current, which is shown above left. It doesn't usually make sense to speak of a "low output that sources current", or a "high output that sinks current", so that table doesn't describe those conditions.
It is assumed that when an output is supposed to be low (0V), then it will sink current through the load, and that load will tend to prevent the output from dropping all the way to 0V. The load is "pulling up", fighting against the output trying to "pull down", as indicated by the \$V_O\$ parameter in the "sinking" section of the table, which you'll notice is not quite 0V. For instance, typically, when \$V_{DD}=+5V\$, if you load the output by having it sink 1mA of current from +5V, that output can't get all the way to zero, typically being closer to +0.4V. In the worst case, for the output to be 0.4V or lower, the manufacturer only guarantees an ability to sink up to 0.51mA.
When sourcing current, similar constraints and guarantees are also described in that table. Since current is then flowing out of the output, through the load to ground, the table describes the IC's limited ability to "pull up" its output in an attempt to hold it near \$V_{DD}\$, while the load now "pulls down". The manufacturer guarantees only +2.5V output (when \$V_{DD}=+5V)\$ when sourcing 1.6mA!
Output short circuit current specifications are of no use to you, if the load isn't exactly a short-circuit. They describes the current that flows when there's no potential difference across a 0Ω load, in which case there cannot be any power delivered to that load. That is not the prevailing condition if the load were an an LED and resistor pair. Also I want to point out that in a short-circuit condition, where no power is being delivered to the "short-circuit", the entire \$P=I_{OUT}\times V_{DD}\$ is being dissipated inside the IC itself. The concern isn't power being delivered, but rather power being consumed but not delivered.
The table does suggest that a typical IC will sink and source 1mA of current, while keeping the output within 0.4V of the supply potential (either +4.6V or +0.4V). 1mA is more than enough to brightly illuminate a modern LED, and this circuit will very probably work to illuminate a red LED when low, and a green LED when high:

simulate this circuit
Sadly, though, it's not guaranteed to work. If you can make do with 500μA of LED current, then it's certainly fine, but for more current you can only guarantee success by requiring the IC to sink/source less than 500μA, where it's certain to produce outputs very close to 0V and +5V, and use transistors to do the heavy lifting:

simulate this circuit
Alternatively "buffer" the weak output with a gate designed to drive higher currents, such as the 4050:

simulate this circuit
The two "buffer" circuits above have another benefit that might not be obvious at first. Without the buffer, the LED loads limit the 4020's output voltage swing, possibly to the point where they are no longer valid (within specification) digital logic levels. That may prevent you from using that same output for other digital inputs, or for further processing elsewhere. Using buffers ensures that the output potentials of the weak 4020 are still very close to 0V or +5V, remaining valid and unambiguous logic levels.

A great thanks, I understood a lot of things about this table of value. I was not at all comfortable with those values in the data sheet and you correctly pin-pointed my uneasiness.

It would help to say which datasheet you have trouble with, not all are similarly  structured. Also it would help to say which articles or sources have those claims you stated, they might be wrong or it is possible you just interpreted something incorrectly.
Yes, short circuiting a chip output will have some current that is limited by the weak output driver by the overload condition. It's not deliberately limited so you can drive short circuits or arbitrary loads with it. The weak output simply cannot pass more and it may dissipate too much power and damage.
So you cannot safely drive a LED without a resistor. The power needs to be dissipated somewhere, and the correct place to dissipate the power is not inside the chip but in the external resistor.

Why no maximum

The datasheet also tells you minimum and typical current, because you need to meet a certain outout voltage for the input of the next chip. Basically, it means you are guaranteed to be able to pull at least this amount of current to meet the voltage limit, but it typically can provide more current to meet the limit. Basically, if some chips could drive more current and meet the voltage limit, it would be the max section, but as you see, you can't ever use that value because the mininum current is what you need so all chips work within the output voltage limits.

Why negative

The numbers are negative just because the current is out of the pin, not into it.

Why minimum
Again the minimum current is not into a short circuit. It's the current that the output is guaranteed to provide while keeping output voltage within guaranteed limits. A short circuit will override your output voltage and then you have higher short circuit current.

You can expect that short circuit current is limited to some but unsafe value because the transistors are weak, and they might overheat and damage under short circuit. If 5V and 100mW limit, that's 20mA current. Never think it's OK to short-circuit something and it will survive.

You don't need to think if you need a resistor or not, overloading circuits is not what should be done, but hobbyists and newbies do that anyway and then their circuits are not reliable or damage. You have a data sheet which says at 5V, and 0.4V drop inside the chip, you can pull at least 0.5mA, and also maybe curves that give you guaranteed drop with some load current. Simply use a resistor to drop the rest of the voltage at that current, based on the voltage of your LED. And the current you want.


If you want more current with stronger chips, consider 7400 series CMOS chips.

Thank you. I added some references in the initial question, and where I found that no resistor is needed.  I do not specifically requires more power, at the end I will drive a transistor as a switch for several LED. So it is mostly to understand how I connect several IC between them, and at the end which resistor I will need to drive the transistor. I take the LED as a basis to try understanding all of that.

CD4000 series circuits are low "level currents", although they can be used between 5 and 15 V.
The maximum current are from +/- 1mA to +/- 6 mA (depending of supply voltages).
Short-circuits are not "allowed", as usual.
The outputs can drive little LEDs with "little" current (~ 1 mA).
Just use a serial resistor limiting current (something like 500 -> 1k).


Thanks for the confirmation. But how can I understand that by reading the data sheet? I try to be autonomous by reading documentation.
I observe far more than just 1mA with a 5V power supply on my LED without resistor. So why would I put a 500/1K resistor since the current is already far below 10 mA? And what is the capacitor for in your schematic?

The capacitor is "supply decoupling". You must use one wired nearest the pins "power supply" of the circuit for  absorbing the fast transients. A resistor can "always" be used to limit the current.

@VincentHiribarren you cannot be effectively autonomous by reading the datasheets only. The datasheet authors assume that the reader has a general understanding of the underlying technology.  Other documents (e.g. application notes, design guides or textbooks) may get you there.



no maximum?


The Fairchild CD4024BC datasheet linked in the question has an Absolute Maximum Ratings section which gives a maximum power dissipation for the package:

Power Dissipation (PD)

Dual-In-Line 700 mW
Small Outline 500 mW


The TI CD4024B datasheet gives a maximum power dissipation for the complete package and each output transistor:



So, while the absolute maximum output current isn't specified, from the absolute maximum power dissipation and the graphs of output voltage .vs. output current you could in theory estimate the absolute maximum output current to avoid the absolute maximum power dissipation from being exceeded. This is complicated by the graphs of output voltage .vs. output current showing typical values, and the actual curves can vary between devices.
As mentioned by the other answer for reliable operation power should be dissipated externally to the CD4024B logic IC.

Thank you. As I "feared", it seems the maximum power dissipation is the right piece of information and I need to compute what I want from that. Not really easy to catch and understand for the hobbyist I am.

I'm not going to repeat the detail in the other excellent answers, just give a reason for one question that might arise out of them. Why can you short circuit the output without apparent damage?
Many ICs have output current limited to a level that momentary (less than 500 ms typically) shorts to ground do not cause damage. This is because when engineers are probing circuits, a common accident is to have a trailing scope probe ground lead drop on a pin. If this caused ICs to fail, they would rapidly get a bad name as fragile. It's fairly straightforward to design this protection in for most circuits, so it is done. If a 500 ms short is going to be warranted, then typically circuits will survive a much longer short to ground, though they cannot be expected to survive that indefinitely.
